# How to increase my root partition size using Gparted, ubuntu 16.04 dual boot?

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, resize

I have dual boot with Windows 8.1 and ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I want to increase my root (/) partition size.[This are my partitions in laptop.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3OuJ.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu.  I'm not sure what you want us to tell you, I'd suggest shrinking the 'dns' partition, then growing your  '/' paritition, but I have no idea what is in 'dns' so can't know the consequences. I'd use `gparted` myself, but lots of tools would do it (your / must be unmounted, easiest with 'live' media such as install media, but it's your choice).  The growing of / may cause grub to have issues (if you use it), so the mbr (if you use it; the pointer to where / is on disk) may need re-writing, but I'd only fix this if you have issues with it.

Comment: yes ..the 'dns' partition is empty, I want to shrink that and increase '/' partition size.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions.   If you want to use `gparted`, you'll find youtube videos telling you how, let alone documentation (eg. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GParted though you'll want to click the gparted link).  You can use your existing Ubuntu to resize or delete 'dns', but it'll be easier to boot a 'live' OS (so / is unmounted; use Ubuntu install media) so / isn't in use to increase it's size.  If you boot and grub-rescue is visible, enter commands to boot Ubuntu, or return to 'live' media to correct, covered here too.